# How to use python to edit a column with linked data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text data file containing multi-columns, rows and sections. Herein, I want to delete rows which their 5th or 6th or 7th columns larger than 50.

Challenges are:

1. In 'Atoms' section,  the first column is called 'Atom_id'. This 'Atom_id' is used in the 3rd or 4th columns of 'Bond' section. So deleted 'atom_id' should also be deleted at 'Bond' section, if it is available at its 3rd or 4th column.
2. Updating 'Atom_id' and 'Bond_id' to be continuous. But, the problem is about 3rd or 4th columns of 'Bond' section, which should be updated correspondingly.

Any comments or suggestions will be highly appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Here is the my minimized data file.

```
#Atoms
#Atom_id    molecules_id    atom_type   charge  x_coor  y_coor  z_coor
       1       1     2    -0.834           60.243           56.013           55.451  
       2       1     1     0.417           1.061            6.406            5.263  
       3       1     1     0.417           3.513            2.071             5.526  
       4       2     2    -0.834             4.14           6.861            5.328  
       5       2     1     0.417            4.322            6.96            5.317  
       6       2     1     0.417            3.303           1.922            4.912  
       7       3     2    -0.834           12.756           53.344            3.856  
       8       3     1     0.417           12.527           53.366            4.833  
       9       3     1     0.417           12.039           53.747            3.454  
      10       4     2    -0.834           1.402            7.122           13.392  
      
 #Bonds
 #Bond_id   bond_type   atom_id atom_id
       1       2       1       2    
       2       2       1       3    
       3       2       4       5  
       4       2       4       6   
       5       2       7       8   
       6       2       7       9   
       7       2      10      11   
       8       2      10      12   
       9       2      13      14   
      10       2      13      15    
      11       2      16      17
```

It seems it would be better to clean the data and separate these sections into two different files.  Is it  easier to write the script for separated sections?

Comment: assuming that this table is a (pandas) dataframe, then just use `df.apply()` or similar.

Comment: for alternatively a pattern like `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you require: I first split the text file into two and then used pd.read_csv to form 2 dataframes (named atoms and bonds) of the forms show abbreviated below:

```
   Atom_id  molecules_id  atom_type  charge  x_coor  y_coor  z_coor
0        1             1          2  -0.834  60.243  56.013  55.451
1        2             1          1   0.417   1.061   6.406   5.263
...
    Bond_id  bond_type  atom_id  atom_id.1
0         1          2        1          2
1         2          2        1          3
...
```

Then select all rows from atom DF which have any of last 3 rows > 50

```
atoms2 = atoms[(atoms['x_coor'].gt(50)) | (atoms['y_coor'].gt(50))| (atoms['z_coor'].gt(50))]
```

then save the values of Atom_id which meet this criterion in a List

```
atomID = atoms2['Atom_id'].to_list()
```

then use this List to remove rows from the original DFs

```
atom3 = atoms[~(atoms['Atom_id'].isin(atomID))]

bonds2 = bonds[~((bonds['atom_id'].isin(atomID)) | (bonds['atom_id.1'].isin(atomID)))]
```

which gives for the two DFs

```
   Atom_id  molecules_id  atom_type  charge  x_coor  y_coor  z_coor
1        2             1          1   0.417   1.061   6.406   5.263
2        3             1          1   0.417   3.513   2.071   5.526
3        4             2          2  -0.834   4.140   6.861   5.328
4        5             2          1   0.417   4.322   6.960   5.317
5        6             2          1   0.417   3.303   1.922   4.912
9       10             4          2  -0.834   1.402   7.122  13.392

    Bond_id  bond_type  atom_id  atom_id.1
2         3          2        4          5
3         4          2        4          6
6         7          2       10         11
7         8          2       10         12
8         9          2       13         14
9        10          2       13         15
10       11          2       16         17
```

You could then if required write out these DFs into a text file or whatever is required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fruitful answer. But, there is one challenge remained! If you look at the 'atom id' at second section (Bond), it shows old 'Atom_id'. They need to be revised based on the new continuous Atom_id.

Comment: I'm sure this would be easy to fix but I don't understand what you mean by continuous. Please explain or edit question to show required output.

Comment: I mean, increasing number started from 1, 2, 3 into n.  In the other words, we have a new atom_id located at 1st column and old one at 2nd columns of your output data (atom section). So, atom_id used at 'Bond' section are based on the old one. My question: is there a command to modify atom_id at the 'Bond' section?

Comment: Do you mean that in the final Bond DF the `atom_id` column should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and the other columns remain as they are. This issue demonstrates why it is always best to provide an expected result which clarifies the requirement.